# Search multiple log files

Tags: windows

Is there a good application to search for a string in multiple log files?

I run Sharepoint 2010 on a server, which writes log files to multiple files (well in a rolling log method) so I may want to find a certain error in all the files. What would be a good tool for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The [`find`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find_%28command%29) command can search multiple files for a specific string.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Log Parser, its an older resource tool kit tool that while built for IIS logs is quite flexable.  A search for log parser and sharepoint will net you quite a few recomended use cases.

Answer (score 0):

For both Unix and Windows system, I'm a big fan of [betterGrep](http://betterthangrep.com/).

It should be noted, it's command line tool.